# How can tables be left justified - i.e., in a generated pdf document using pipeline and xmlparser?

Tags: java, css, itext

I'm using the "pipeline" technique, below, to convert an html string into PDF format.

It works fine, except, that the html tables apparently default to the center of the page.
--Is this the default behavior?  If so, is there any work-a-round?

Anyway, I would like the tables to be ***left*** justified.

How can I accomplish this?

Note: "text-align: left;" and "margin-left: 5px", for example, have NO effect...  The old-fashioned "align: left" attribute is not supported, either.

Thanks for any help/guidance!

---

## java code snippet:

```
         -
         -
         -
        document.open();

        HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);

        htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

        // CSS
        CSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
        InputStream csspathtest = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("css/testpdf.css");            
        CssFile cssfiletest = XMLWorkerHelper.getCSS(csspathtest);
        cssResolver.addCss(cssfiletest);             

        Pipeline<?> pipeline =  new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer)));

        XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
        XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
        p.parse(is); //new FileInputStream("results/demo2/walden.html"));

        // step     
        document.close();
         -
         -
         -
```

---

## css snippet:

```
    div
    {
        margin-left: 5px;
        padding-left: 5px;
    }

    h2
    {
        color:blue;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 16pt;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    h6
    {
        color:#777;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14pt;
        margin-bottom: 20px;    
    }

    p
    {
        color: green;
        text-align: center; 
        font-style: italic;    
        font-size: 12pt;
        margin-bottom: 20px;    
    }

    table
    {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: blue;
        border-color: #777;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: .1px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        text-align: left;
        vertical-align: top;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        margin-left: 5px;
        padding-left: 5px;
    }


    th
    {
        color: #777;
        font-size: 10pt;
        background-color: lightgrey;
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: left;
        vertical-align: top;    
    }

    td
    {
        font-size: 8pt;
        color: navy;
        border-top-color: #777;
        border-top-width: .01px;       
        padding: 5px;   
        text-align: left;
        vertical-align: top;     
    }
```

Comment: By default, tables are aligned to the left in HTML.  Aligning a table element is typically done with margins (left: `margin-left: 0; margin-right: auto`, center: `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto`, right: `margin-left: auto; margin-right: 0`).

Comment: Hi Cimmanon.  I tried, for example, using "margin-left: 5px" on both the table and the div that contains it,  but, to no effect.  Is there something else I'm missing? Thx, s.

Comment: It might be a limitation of the process of converting it to PDF using this technique.  If adjusting the margins doesn't help, there's not much else I can suggest.

Comment: Cimmanon - have you read any documentation that indicates that this is the default behavior (i.e., to center all tables) for the XmlParser?  I'm trying to find a work-a-round, but, I dont want to waste too much time if it is simply not possible.